# Why won't the log out button show?

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I'm already logged in, but the log out button doesn't show. The url shows login=success. Here's my code for index.php

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>

<body>

    <div class="loginbox">
        <img src="avatar.png" class="avatar">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>

        <?php

        if (isset($_SESSION['key'])) {
            echo 
            '<form action="includes/logout.inc.php" method="POST">
            <button type="submit" name="submitLogout"> Log Out </button>
            </form>';}
        else{
            $str = "Don't have an account?";
            echo 
            "<form action='includes/login.inc.php' method='POST'>
            <p class='formtextlg'><input type='text' name='EmailUsername' placeholder='Email or Username'><br></p>
            <p class='formtextlg'><input type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password'><br></p>
            <p class='formtextlg'><input type='submit' name='submitLogin' value='Submit'></p><br>
            <p class='formtextlg'><a href=''>Lost your password?</a><br></p>
            <p class='formtextlg'><a href='signup.php'>$str</a><br></p>
            </form>";}

        ?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

At the very first line of header.php, I have the session_start(); function. Here's my code for login.inc.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_POST['submitLogin'])) {
    include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    $EmailUsername = $_POST['EmailUsername'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if (empty($EmailUsername)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty1"); exit();}
    else{
        if (empty($password)) {
            header("Location: ../index.php?login=empty2"); exit();}
        else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='$EmailUsername' || user_username='$EmailUsername'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

            if ($resultCheck < 1) {
                header("Location: ../index.php?login=error"); exit();}
            else{
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($password, $row['user_password']);

                if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error"); exit();}
                elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                        $_SESSION['key'] = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['first'] = $row['user_first'];
                        $_SESSION['last'] = $row['user_last'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['user_email'];
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['user_username'];
                        header("Location: ../home.php?login=success"); exit();}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
}
```

Please help me find where I went wrong, I am quite new to php, and I'm just trying to apply what I learned from following a youtube playlist.

Comment: It seems like your `$_SESSION['key']` isn't set. Are your users successfully logging in? If they are, there's no reason why the button shouldn't show. Does it show up in the DOM? Perhaps some CSS rules are hiding it.

Comment: Have you called `session_start();` in `index.php`?

Comment: I already fixed it. Thanks for the replies! :) @ObsidianAge, somehow I was I able to figure out that it wasn't because of the css rules. So I tried to figure out why $_SESSION['key'] was not set. Thaaaank youuu for your words! Btw, what's DOM?